# row is not inserting due to SP2-0552 error

Tags: sql, oracle

I was trying to insert a row in a table. The below given error occurred while inserting

I don't know for what reason it occurred

```
SQL> insert into priya1 values ('CB','000304105000','A023596','MSC','A',05/7/2013
 5:33:57 AM);
```

> SP2-0552: Bind variable "33" not declared.

Comment: -1 because this is a syntax error question and therefore too localized to be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because your date string is not correct, it is not even a string and because in many cases it will not be recognized as a date. Don't depend on defaults for date formats that happen to be in effect, make sure that your code always works by specifying what you insert.
In this case use:

```
create table z (z date);
insert into z (z) values (to_date('05/7/2013 5:33:57 AM','dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss am'));
1 rij is aangemaakt.
```

Answer (score 0):

i found an another way for this problem i solved using the given below query and then i inserted rows without adding to_date

alter session set nls_date_format='yyyy/mm/dd hh:mi:ss am';

Answer (score 0):

it may be case when data contains single quote also produces this error for date column. in that case replace single quote with two single quotes. then record will insert

Answer (score -1):

put the date time value in single quote

```
insert into priya1 values ('CB','000304105000','A023596','MSC','A','05/7/2013
 5:33:57 AM');
```

Comment: "Schema Creation Failed: ORA-01843: not a valid month" [SQL Fiddle](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dj6aC.png)

Comment: try to get current datetime using sql funtion getdate() and use same format

Comment: There is no "GETDATE()" function in Oracle RDBMS. Use `SYSDATE,  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, LOCALTIMESTAMP or CURRENT_DATE`.

Comment: Don't enter dates or times as string value. Use TO_DATE() function.

Comment: Relying on implicit data type conversion (string -> date) is a bad advice.